# Genymotion save snapshots of Android Virtual Devices

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I am using Genymotion version 3.1.0 on Mac OSX and I created an Android virtual device using it for Google Pixel 3a (Android version 9.0 and API level 28).

I've installed some apps inside this virtual device and also modified a few settings. Now, I want to save this state as a snapshot. Let's call it "snapshot A".

I would like to revert to "snapshot A" anytime I want even after making more changes to the AVD. Something similar to the concept of snapshots in VMWare. Is it possible?

Right now, I only see the option to do a "Factory reset" in Genymotion for a virtual device. However, factory reset will not revert the AVD to the state where I had some apps on it installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar using Genymotion Cloning feature (right-click on the device --> Duplicate).